# Migration rejection followed by repost on original site closed as duplicate, how do I proceed?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, asking-questions

I had asked a question on the IoT and they immediately migrated it over to Ask Different, where it sat for a while (almost 2 weeks) and no answers.

A moderator from Ask Different thought it should be asked again in IoT and told me how to do it, which I did. I flagged my question, deleted it, and when that happened, I reopened the question "A splitter to carry more than just audio"

Well today I was beaten up pretty bad, from asking a duplicate question to being off topic, then when asked what I though IoT meant I answered it and was, well, told lawyering will not help.

I'm a member of very small group of developers, including the creator of SpriteBASIC and Mike Westerfield, who wrote techBASIC, and basically wrote the book on IoT.

I knew he was trying very hard to finish his new book, and I had already wrote him a lengthy paper about math and number in techBASIC, but I decided that I needed an expert to see if there was an answer, so I asked him the question as written here and he responded back.

I flagged the moderator telling what happened over at IoT and that I had an answer. It isn't pretty but a starting point, and asked for him to undelete and unlock so I can anwser the question here.

However, my question is still locked.

How do I go about getting it unlocked so I can answer the question which may start more people helping me or at least I will have an answer to close out the question and get my dignity back (I lost all my reputation points in the IoT, I will not repeat any comments as this is not the place for it).

I would like a positive outcome on this.

Also, besides writing a request here, it there a way that the person who asked the question can request it be unlocked by allowing him to flag the unlock itself? Or something that would be done in a way that would not require a request here or in a chat (not everyone has chat privileges).

Comment: This seems like a right mess. I don't agree with the advice you received to ask again on IoT.SE. You should never repost a question, so I understand how that may not have been well received. Rather, the original question should have been reopened if that was the right site for the question. I'm not sure you've asked this on the correct Meta though — wouldn't this be better asked at the IoT meta rather than Ask Different? Also, neither of your questions on IoT are locked and I don't see what Community has to do with your question?

Comment: @grgarside I agree, but bouncing it back to IoT was not an option at the time the issue came at.

Comment: I would ask them, but it was locked when I deleted it. I'm pretty new to Stack Exchange and When they said that the question was migrated of IoT to Ask Different, what was there to reopen on IoT if it no longer existed? Now I did not lose any reputation points on that same question on AD, just all of them on IoT.

Comment: @patrix Could you expand on this comment? I'm not sure I fully understand what you said, am I missing some context?

Comment: @George Migrated questions aren't removed from the original site; they're still there and can be reopened if necessary.

Comment: @grgarside The question was migrated from IoT to AD on Feb 19th. It didn't gather a lot of attention, but when I tried to bounce it back to IoT on Feb 25th I wasn't able to reject the migration any longer (I assume there is a time limit for this, didn't follow up on this though). That's why I recommended to ask for a reopen on IoT directly instead.

Comment: @grgarside Thanks. I'll never make that mistake again, and part of the answer I got from Mike Westerfield is hardware and Apple policy.

Comment: @grgarside Unfortunately the question seems to be off-topic on IoT in general (see comments there), which left George's question in a rather strange state.

Comment: @patrix Seems like something got misinterpreted then, because asking for reopening is definitely the best scenario but OP reposted the entire question, leading to usual downvotes and duplicate closure. This seems to be where the problem is here unless I'm misunderstanding this Meta question entirely.

Comment: I've edited the title to try to be closer to what I believe is the problem here. Feel free to edit further or if the reference to Community was part of the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, the locking was my mistake. I was handling the flag while on the commute back home and didn't realize that the question was both deleted *and* locked. It's unlocked now.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. At least I was able to get the answer up now with the information that explains why it's kept to hobby-like questions. There is real money when looking into real solutions that requires Apple's technology, hardware or knowledge. Maybe someone can sweet-talk them into giving me back my 15 rep points back???? Thanks for your understanding and help.

Comment: @GeorgeMcGinn Things related to your IoT post need to be addressed at the meta site of IoT. It's beyond the power of the moderators to change reputation though.